# Why does this simple C# UWP Win2D program occasionally fail to render an image

Tags: c#, uwp, win2d

**Hi, my first post so please be gentle :)**

I have written this simple C# UWP Win2D program that on occasions randomly fails to render the image on screen.
The program runs without problems roughly 90% of the time, and as it should, it renders the image, 
oddly though every now and then it fails to render it.

When it fails, it still clears the canvas to the correct colour but it does not render anything else.
The program seems to be running properly but when I place a break point on either the draw method or the update method a break does not occur.

'Break all' does break the program but it informs me 
"Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code 
(typically system or framework code)"

I hope this explains the situation that I am currently facing, I have included the code that is causing this problem,
hopefully someone more knowledgeable than me can help me find a remedy.

**Here is my XAML code ...**

```
<Page
    x:Class="TheGrid.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TheGrid"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:canvas="using:Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    Unloaded="Page_Unloaded">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <canvas:CanvasAnimatedControl 
            x:Name="canvas" 
            ClearColor="Bisque" Update="canvas_Update" Draw="canvas_Draw" CreateResources="canvas_CreateResources"
            />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**And here is the C# code behind ...**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        CanvasBitmap bitmap1;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void canvas_CreateResources(CanvasAnimatedControl sender, CanvasCreateResourcesEventArgs args)
        {
            args.TrackAsyncAction(Canvas_CreateResourcesAsync(sender).AsAsyncAction());
        }
        async Task Canvas_CreateResourcesAsync(CanvasAnimatedControl sender)
        {
            bitmap1 = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(sender, "Assets/Images/testimage.png");
        }     
        private void canvas_Update(ICanvasAnimatedControl sender, CanvasAnimatedUpdateEventArgs args)
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
        private void canvas_Draw(ICanvasAnimatedControl sender, CanvasAnimatedDrawEventArgs args)
        {
            args.DrawingSession.DrawImage(bitmap1, 256, 256);
        }
        private void Page_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.canvas.RemoveFromVisualTree();
            this.canvas = null;
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance for any help you may be able to offer, please let me know if more information is required.

Edit 1.)
I have tried to simplify the problem by removing

`args.TrackAsyncAction(Canvas_CreateResourcesAsync(sender).AsAsyncAction());`

**and**

`async Task Canvas_CreateResourcesAsync(CanvasAnimatedControl sender)
 {
    bitmap1 = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(sender, "Assets/Images/testimage.png");
 }`

**and replacing**

`args.DrawingSession.DrawImage(bitmap1, 256, 256);`

**with**

`args.DrawingSession.DrawCircle(256, 256, 128, Colors.Black, 16);`

This seems to prevent the problem from occurring, so I can only presume that it is a problem with the async pattern that I am using.

Comment: When you say "sometimes it doesn't work" do you mean "sometimes when launched the app it doesn't work" or "sometimes, while the app is running, the image disappears"?

Have you tried running with break on all exceptions enabled?  (ie go to "Exception Settings" and make sure that there's a check mark next to "Common Language Exceptions").

Also, what happens when you run with mixed (native & managed) debugging enabled?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in here

```
private void canvas_CreateResources(CanvasAnimatedControl sender, CanvasCreateResourcesEventArgs args)
    {
        args.TrackAsyncAction(Canvas_CreateResourcesAsync(sender).AsAsyncAction());
    }
```

When using async, my teacher told me to always use await and async function. Because this will cause problem.

Some reading source : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

Comment: [TrackAsyncAction](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/M_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_UI_CanvasCreateResourcesEventArgs_TrackAsyncAction.htm) is a default Win2D idiom for performing asynchronous resource loading. You can't use await in CreateResources handler. [Some more info.](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D/issues/104)